# Positioning floating action button at bottom right

Tags: android, layout, floating-action-button

I implemented a floating action button inside a fragment, placing it at the bottom right with the following source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">


 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/listtipologie"
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:clickable="false"
     android:divider="@null"
     android:dividerHeight="10dp"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
     android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
     android:padding="10dip"></ListView>

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     android:id="@+id/submit"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="16dp"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:gravity="right"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
     android:layout_below="@id/listtipologie"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/submit_icon" />



</LinearLayout>
```

The display on android studio is as follows:

[image]

But when I run it on the phone, the floating action button does not appear in the lower right but a bit higher.
App is displayed in this way:

[image]

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to remove or change the value of `android:layout_margin`?

Comment: Just try to remove android:layout_weight="1" from your listview.

Comment: Use Relative layout instead of Linear layout. Because below attribute :
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

is not for linear layout.

and after that remove android:layout_below="@id/listtipologie"

Comment: android:layout_below="@id/listtipologie" why this line? this does not make any sense here.

Comment: No floating action button remains in that position, I do not understand the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/listtipologie"
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListView.DropDown"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:clickable="false"
     android:divider="@null"
     android:dividerHeight="10dp"
     android:focusable="false"
     android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
     android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
     android:padding="10dip"></ListView>

  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     android:id="@+id/submit"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="16dp"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/submit_icon" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This solution not function. The button not view at the bottom of the screen

Comment: @MirkoMarasco use  android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" with button

Comment: previously it was gravity only, now it is layout_gravity, as this is working on my end @MirkoMarasco